# How can create a read-only SQLOLEDB connection?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I want to create a read-only data connection from within a Visual Studio 2012 application to a MSSQL pre-2005 database.  It is simple enough to connect to but the Read/Write option is not present within the connection properties for pre-2005.  Any ideas how I do this?  Maybe editing the connection string directly?

The reason for this is that the application (in development) will be connecting to a business-critical database application that the business relies on.  There can be no risk of editing the database.

Comment: What about connecting with a user with only required privileges, i.e. read only privileges?